# Reverse proxying a Websocket upstream with Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

I was going to ask on the main SO boards, but figured this place would be more appropriate.

I am wanting to use cloudflare on my main website and then use `nginx` to reverse proxy a directory to my `websocket` gameserver.

**NGINX server block**:

```
    location /Fonzy/ {
                    proxy_pass http://websocket;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }
```

---

**Upstream block**:

```
upstream websocket {
        least_conn;
        server GAMESERVERIPHERE:9300;
    }
```

My question is, since the cloudflare site will be a different server than my gameserver, will the upstream still work? Or does the upstream block server have to be a local address?

The reason why I am curious is because I am wanting the "protection" from cloudflare, but still want to have my gameserver hidden (or should I say reverse proxied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Nginx to proxy to multiple backends based on the `location`.

In your case there is little value in using the `upstream` module which useful when you have *mutiple* backends for the same app. In your case, a basic `proxy_pass` call should do:

```
proxy_pass http://GAMESERVERIPHERE:9300
```